# Translating code from C++ to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I have the next code in C++:

```
for (long i=0; i < num_iter ; i++)
{
    bp->bpgt(data[i%8], &data[i%8][3]);

    if( bp->mse(&data[i%8][3]) < thresh) 
        break;
}
```

where bpgt is a procedure, and mse is a function, thresh is a Double type, data is a bi-dimensional matrix of Double types.

```
void bpgt(double *in,double *tgt);
double mse(double *tgt);
double data[][4]={
        0,0,0,0,
        0,0,1,1,
    1,1,1,1 };
```

I've tried to pass it to Delphi code:

```
for i := 0 to FNum_Iter - 1 do begin
    FBPN.bpgt(FData[i mod 8], ^FData[i mod 8,3]);

    if FBPN.mse(@FData[i mod 8, 3]) < FThresh then
      Break;
end;
```

but I've failed, because I'm a newbie in C++ and I dont know to translate the "&" operator. May Someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate

```
void bpgt(double *in,double *tgt);
```

as

```
procedure bpgt(var in:double; var tgt: double)
```

Well, something like that, my Delphi is a bit rusty....

That way, in bpgt, you can change the value of tgt (and in).

Your call of bpgt will be

```
FBPN.bpgt(FData[i mod 8], FData[i mod 8,3]);
```

In fact Delphi's var (call by reference) is quite often usable as an exact functional equivalent of C/C++'s passing of pointers.

Comment: Yeah, you've got the semantics right.  You can simplify the function header a little bit by saying "var in, tgt: double".  That doesn't work in C++, but it will in Delphi.  The one caveat is that a C * parameter (pass-by-pointer) can set the pointer to NULL, whereas with a Delphi **var** parameter (pass-by-reference), the pointer can never be **nil** on a value type, such as numbers.  You have to be aware of this when translating a C header that you're going to call from Delphi, because it could break a program invariant if the C routine sets the pointer to NULL.

Comment: Well, I dont think that is the solution, 'cause parameters for BPGT and MSE are arrays of Double types. I know that & (C++) and @ (Delphi) are equivalents but I get always an error of incompatible types. The original C++ code can be found at: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BP.aspx
I've run it and work, So I finish confused.

Comment: Billiardo, please read Mason's and my answer again.  You don't need the @ or whatever anymore.  If your final goal is to learn something about neural networks it's probably simpler to get some Delphi NN code and play around with that.  Like this one, found on Torry's http://www.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=6870

Answer (score 2):

This is based on your reply to Fvu's answer.  If they're arrays, that can complicate things, since C doesn't have real arrays, just pointers sprinkled with a light coating of powdered syntactic sugar.  The solution depends on whether you're translating this completely into Delphi, or trying to write a Delphi routine that will work with C code.

If you're doing pure Delphi, declare an array type, like so

```
type
   TDoubleArray = array[0..length] of double; //or "array of double" for a dynamic array
```

Then declare the parameter of the function as `var Data: TDoubleArray`.  If this is a dynamic array, have your **for** loop go from `0 to high(Data);`

If this needs to work with C:

Because C doesn't have real arrays, you need to do some extra work.  Declare your type like this:

```
type
   TCDoubleArray = array[0..65535] of double;
   PCDoubleArray = ^TCDoubleArray;
```

Any sufficiently large value will work for the upper bound of the array. We're not going to use all of it anyway. It just has to be bigger than you'll ever use.  Make the parameter type a PCDoubleArray, which corresponds to `double *`.  You'll need to pass an extra parameter, which tells you where the end point of the array is.  Have your for loop go from 0 to the end point, and access it by saying something like `FData^[i mod 8]`.

Answer (score 0):

The & allows you to send the address of the variable into the function, rather than it's value. This call by reference allows the function to alter the value of the variable. I don't know the equivalent Delphi mechanism, but you want to pass the reference of your variable there, or change the procedure to a function, return the value and store it in the original variable.

Comment: The Delphi equivalent to & is @, and ptr^ is equiv to *ptr (from very rusty memory). But the usual method in Delphi is to use a var parameter as suggested by fvu.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, try this:

```
for i := 0 to FNum_Iter - 1 do begin
    FBPN.bpgt(FData[i mod 8], FData[i mod 8,3]);

    if FBPN.mse(FData[i mod 8, 3]) < FThresh then
      Break;
end;
```

Sorry, but I don't have delphi here to compile and try it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Over at [Rudy's Delphi Corner](http://rvelthuis.de/index.html), he has an [excellent article about the pitfalls of converting C/C++ to Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html). In my opinion, this is essential information when attempting this task. Here is the description:

> This article is meant for everyone who
>   needs to translate C/C++ headers to
>   Delphi. I want to share some of the
>   pitfalls you can encounter when
>   converting from C or C++. This article
>   is not a tutorial, just a discussion
>   of frequently encountered problem
>   cases. It is meant for the beginner as
>   well as for the more experienced
>   translator of C and C++.

He also wrote a "[Conversion Helper Package](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/convertpack.html)" that installs into the Delphi IDE which aids in converting C/C++ code to Delphi:

[image]
<sub>(source: [rvelthuis.de](http://rvelthuis.de/images/convertpackshaded.png))</sub>

His other relevant articles on this topic include:

- [Using C++ Objects in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html)
- [Using C object files in Delphi](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html)